# What class/racial abilities or spells cause vulnerability in other creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, vulnerability

I am looking for ways to cause my opponents to be [vulnerable](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat) to the damage I deal in combat.

I am not interested in ignoring resistance, I am only looking to cause the vulnerability condition.
Ideally I would like it to apply to any damage type I am dealing in the moment, however at this point any type of vulnerability will do, as I have not found any on my own.

What are some of the spells, and class/racial abilities or magic items that create this condition in others?  Oficial WotC content only please. (no Unearthed Arcana)

Comment: Actually, I believe this is a duplicate (or at least partial duplicate) of the following, which was closed as being too broad: "[What spells or other effects cause weakness to a certain damage type?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101203)"

Comment: It is similar but not really a duplicate and the other question has no answers and not enough detail.  Ill add details to this one.

Comment: I will say that I'm unsure whether that other question *should* have been closed (though it mentioning *elemental bane* doesn't make its criteria very clear) since we have numerous open questions that are answered by lengthy lists: [Example #1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125845), [Example #2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99426), [Example #3](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171914), [Example #4](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120405), [Example #5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171218), [Example #6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177073), and *plenty* more.

Comment: I’ve started a community wiki answer. Ideally, people who wish to respond would just add their findings to that answer instead of creating more answers, since the contents of any additional answers will be added to it anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Class features:

- Cleric, Grave Domain, Path to the Grave
- Sorcerer, Wild Magic Origin, Wild Magic Surge (95-96)

Racial traits:

- Didn’t find any yet.

Spells:

- *Hallow* (Energy Vulnerability)
- *Contagion* (Flesh Rot)

(Magic) Items:

- Blight Ichor
- Claw of the Wyrm Rune
- Staff of the Forgotten One